# Drop down div on focus of search box using xoxco

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Xoxco's plugin for tag input found here:

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

In my modification, I've used JQuery's `focus()` function

```
<input id="tags_1" class="tag-holder" type="text" class="tags"  /></p>      
    <div id="std" style="display:none;">
        <span id='pdf' onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">PDF</span>
        <p id="reset" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">Reset Tags</p>
    </div>
```

My JQuery for this is

```
$('#tags_1').focus(function(){
        $('#std').css('display','block');
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when used with my modification of the plugin. It does work separately without using the plugin. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: but its working here : http://jsfiddle.net/G2a7T/

Comment: Try `on` event. Eg: `$('#tags_1').on('focus',function(){      $('#std').css('display','block');});`

Comment: `$('#std').show();` would do that too.

Comment: @Era, Like I mentioned in the OP, it works separately, but the moment I integrate it with the xoxco plugin, it breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the issue is it adds a `_tag` in your elements id and that id is no more available so you have to target this id `#tag_1_tag`:

so your code should be like this:

*order matters*

```
$('#tags_1').tagsInput({width: 'auto'}); //<----tagInput applied

$('#tags_1_tag').focus(function(){  //<-----this id has to be the target now
    $('#std').css('display','block');
});
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ4VT/)

or even you can use attribute selectors:

```
$('[id^="tags_1"]').focus(function(){  //<-----this id has to be the target now
    $('#std').css('display','block');
});
```

#### [Demo with attribute selector](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ4VT/1/)